# Switch between Windows 7 and Ubuntu without rebooting?

Tags: 12.04, windows

Is this possible? It's kind of a pain that I would like to get past.

Comment: No, current hardware doesn't support running two OS a the same time.

Answer (score 0):

No,it is not possible to switch between windows 7 and Ubuntu without rebooting, but you can access windows 7 files(partitions) from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run both operating systems at a time in any part of the PC world. You can't run both simultaneously. At any given time, you can only run one system. Though, you can use virtual box and run a guest system inside of a host system.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly - but if your hardware supports virtualization, you can run Windows 7 in a VM while running Ubuntu, with excellent performance for anything *except* 3D gaming.  (If you want 3D gaming, you need to be running Windows natively.)

[image: Windows 7 VM]

If you get Spice support enabled and working - which, admittedly, is currently a PITA - video and sound performance is easily good enough to, for example, watch video clips on YouTube in your Windows 7 VM.  For simple work or web browsing, you don't even need that - the default VNC console or RDP via Remmina is more than sufficient.

Comment: avoid repeating same answers. Edit others question to make it more helpful.